# Internet Explorer view selection source

Tags: internet-explorer

Firefox has this nice feature, highlight text and then view selection source. Is there maybe a way to do this in Internet Explorer 7+? As a developer this is really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use this! 
http://pclancey.com/tutorial/selectsrc/

Comment: That tool is like gold on a monkey sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IEToys](http://www.bayden.com/ietoys/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a Javascript implementation of 'View Selection Source'](http://pclancey.com/tutorial/selectsrc/), with optional instructions for editing the registry to add it to the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

Page suggested above has moved to:

http://www.pclancey.com/legacy/tutorial/selectsrc/